# What's the iOS equivalent of MesagingCenter?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

How can I send messages between disparate components in iOS?

i.e. How does one do this using iOS...?

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "LoggedIn");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

To use it, define your notification, register an observer, and finally post the notification, e.g.

```
let loggedIn = Notification.Name("LoggedIn")

let nc = NotificationCenter.default
nc.addObserver(forName: .loggedIn, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    // handle loggedIn notification
}

// ... elsewhere: post
nc.post(name: .loggedIn, object: nil)
```